# Invalid JSON for file name

Tags: json

I am trying to create a JSON file and am trying to validate it via http://jsonlint.com/

This is a valid json :

```
{
    "rule": "rules.json",
    "publisher": "nbc",
    "output": "D:\temp"
}
```

This is the invalid one :

```
{
    "rule": "rules.json",
    "publisher": "nbc",
    "output": "D:\temp\"
}
```

The output in the invalid one has an extra \

Comment: you are escaping the last quote. try `"D:\\temp\\"`

Comment: Also it seems that \t could produce an unwanted tab character.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax. In particular, pay attention to the `\\` "escape" character and it's special meaning.